# Best data structure to represent a game board

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

I'm trying to bring a board game to the computer world, and the board consists of 16 spaces, 6 for each side and 4 in the middle. The board is diamond-shaped and two ends represent both team bases. In the game, peices only move foward towards the enemy"s base (with special abilities of course). So here is my question: what do you think is the best data structure to represent the game board? The first thing that came to my mind was a tree, but I really don't like the idea because there would be two "roots". Any suggestions?

The board looks like this:

```
    &
   & &
 &  &  &
*  *  *  *
 $  $  $
  $  $
    $
```

so the & team can only move towards the $ team and vice-versa, * being neutral territory

Comment: Can you please upload drawing of the board somewhere? I'm not sure I interpreted you description well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it essentially a square?  The diamond shape just a matter of interpretation? Like so ..

```
M A A A
B M A A
B B M A
B B B M
```

if so, maybe just use a 2D array, and use your display system to 'turn it' into a diamond.

**edit**

I think you can map you move set to the array - If your '$' pieces only move up-and-left or up-and-right, that is akin to my 'B' pieces moving only 'up' or 'right'.  Similary, if the '&' pieces only move down-and-left or down-and-right, that's like the 'A' pieces only moving down or left.

The idea is that, internal to the program, think of your data 'up and down', but when you present your game state to your user, just *draw* it in the diamond configuration.

Comment: its exactly a square, but I used diamond because in the case of the square, the peices would have to move diagonally towards the other corner instead of just up or down, wich I find makes alot more sense and is more convenient

Comment: A 2D array is definitely the way to go.  Not only is it a quick and convenient structure, but the movement rules should be easy to code.  Keep it simple!

Answer (score 5):

Your concern is not just how to represent the board but also how to represent the pieces because the board and the pieces need to communicate their mutual presence and effects.

Therefore, how you represent your board will be determined by how you represent your pieces and the rules of the game constraining the board and the pieces.

Your first concern is how to represent the pieces.

A game piece or a game automaton is a perfect model for object oriented programming.

Let me illustrate by dispensing away with the declarations such as public, static, etc.

```
abstract class BasicUnit
{
 // determine constraints of movement here.
 // update position and return new position
 abstract Position move(Direction d);

 abstract Position getPosition();
 Arsenal arsenal;
}

class Worker
extends BasicUnit
{
 Position move(Direct d)
 {
  //whateveer, etc
 }
}

class farmer
extends Worker
{
 Position move(Direct d)
 {
  //whateveer, etc
 }
}

class Warrior
extends BasicUnit
{
 Position move(Direct d)
 {
  //whateveer, etc
 }
}

class Sniper
extends Warrior
{
 Position move(Direct d)
 {
  //whateveer, etc
 }
}
```

Now you have to decide if the positions of pieces on the board is

- board centric: positions of pieces are registered on the board only
- piece centric: positions are registered on pieces only
- redundant: you have to redundantly update both piece and board when a piece is moved.

For most board games, piece-centric would not be a good idea because, you would have to search every piece to determine if a position is occupied.

If board-centric, you would need to search every position of the board to find the position of a piece.

For redundant, you have to ensure that positions registered by both board and pieces are not misaligned. If you plan to allow your game to be played over the internet, where sessions can be paused and hibernated - you might face challenges in synchronising.

So, the answer to your question is - a hashed vector to represent the board.

A hashed vector is a collection with two access doors - one accessed by position, second accessed by key. Your hashed vector would allow you to access

- the board by position to find out what unit is on a position
- the id of the piece to find out where on the board it is.

You cannot represent the board as a tree unless yours is a multidimensional board game. A tree is needed when you have a tree, a ladder, or a castle that sits on a board position, so that when a unit reaches that horizontal position of a board, it would need to advance to the vertical position of the ladder or castle. And in the castle the unit needs to be diverted to numerous rooms. Or on the tree is a witch capable of capturing the unit into a bottle with a confusing escape path. Therefore, using a tree structure to represent your board would present needless complication to programming your game.

It does not matter whether it is square of diamond or circle, etc. You just need to enumerate the position of the board. The method of enumeration must be convenient for your rules to capture.

That means, you should not enumerate one piece as (1,3) and then enumerate its neighbouring piece as (2,7) - it's just common sense. Because the neighbours of (1,3) are (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (0,3), (2,3), (0,4), (1,4) and (2,4) but not (2,7).

Therefore you need a 2-dimensional hashed vector.

To cater to your need of finding out what unit is on the x,y position of your board:

```
BasicUnit getPosition(x,y)
```

As well as, finding out the (x,y) position of a unit.

```
Position getUnit(BasicUnit unit)
```

Then you might plan your game to be expandable so that a player on achieving victory could go on to play the next level which has a different board shape. Your 2-D hashed vector would still be used because you separate presentation layer of your software from its data structure.

You merely insert more positions into your vector.

You can view my Java implementation of a 1-D hashed vector at
http://code.google.com/p/synthfuljava/wiki/HashVector

translate it to your choice of programming language and add one more vector dimension to it.

Comment: I forgot to add that transforming the 1-D hashed vector is a rather simple affair of mapping the abtract (x,y) position to the actual linear position of the 1-D hashed vector.

So if your board is 9 by 9,

transforming (x,y) to vector index is
vectorindex = x + 9*y

Comment: Good post, but a hashed vector is such an overkill for this. The board is only 4x4 meaning hashing will actually slow it down compared to a simple map.

Answer (score 1):

What about two trees with the middle four fields being the same? (I mean referencing the same objects)

Comment: I thought about that too, but wasn't sure what happens if I take a middle field and grab its parents? how would I know wich one to get?
Best answer yet!

Comment: You said that the player can only move forward - so do you need the parent?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a kind of graph. Like:

```
class Field
{
     private List<Field> neighbours;
}
```

Or not a list but an array which contains null references for border fields. Any board can be represented with this.

Comment: This is of course the simplest way of doing things, but I don'T like it because it does not show constraints for left/right movement, and the list of neighbours will not tell you explicitally what region is where.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple array structure? If the board is diamond shaped, it's square/rectangular shaped, right?

```
Dim myBoard(5,5) As Array
```

Of course, if the board is oddly shaped, (like there are spaces and things in the middle) this may not work.

Comment: It can still work out, as long as the things in the middle are diamonds - they can be represented as null values or something similar.